# Emacs: focused buffer modeline font face

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, on the modeline: I would like the name of the currently focused buffer to be bold.

My modeline looks something like this:

```
(setq mode-line-format
  (list "%&"
    " "
    (propertize "%b " 'face 'mode-line-buffer-id)
    "%p of %I"
    " "
    "[%l,%c]"
    'vc-mode
    " "
    'mode-line-modes
    ))
```

I would like "%b" (the name of the buffer) to be bold when the buffer is in focus. I am totally new to elisp. I thought setting the face to a variable that is changed by some "focus-in" hook would be the way to go (and possibly forcing the modeline to be redrawn).

I'm not sure what event I should hook in to. I know about focus-in-hook and focus-out-hook but those are for the frame.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question here and to emacs.SE. Choose one or the other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was [cross-posted simultaneously](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28641/105) to emacs.stackexchange (where it has been edited and answered).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I did not know about the emacs SE at the time. Sorry about that. How do we close it here?

Comment: No problem. You should be able to *delete* it, I think.